# Python program that reorganizes Excel formatting?

Tags: python, excel, database, csv, transpose

I am working on a Python program that aims to take Excel data that is vertical and make it horizontal.

For example, the data is shaped something like this:

County      | State  | Number | Date 
Oakland     | MI     |  19    | 1/12/10 
Oakland     | MI     |  32    | 1/19/10 
Wayne       | MI     |  9     | 1/12/10 
Wayne       | MI     |  6     | 1/19/10

But I want it like this (purposefully excluding the state):

County      |    1/12/10   |   1/19/10
Oakland     |    19        |     32
Wayne       |    9         |      6

(And for the actual data, it’s quite long).

My logic so far: 
Read in the Excel File 
Loop through the counties 
If county name is the same, place # in Row 1? 
Make a new Excel File?

Any ideas of how to write this out? I think I am a little stuck on the syntax here.

Comment: Can you use external libraries, such as pandas?

Comment: @AndrewH Yes I can!

Comment: There is a powershell thing that can do this see: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0 . Is there any reason why you are trying to solve this in python (which is also possible) ?

Comment: @Luuk Oh, I think I am not familiar with powershell. I think I wanted to try Python just so we'd have a quick program to run an Excel file through, since we will be doing this on a regular basis!

Comment: OK, like Andrew mentioned, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)